# How to config spanish stemming in solr 4.9?

Tags: solr

I have installed solr 4.9. I have been using the schema.xml that is included in the folder

> ...\solr4.9.0\example\solr\collection1\conf

I would like to include spanish stemming.
What I have tried is to add the following code, where the schema has the Spanish fieldtype

```xml
<!-- Spanish -->
<fieldtype name="textTypeWithStemming" class="solr.TextField"> 
  <analyzer type="index"> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/> 
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/> 
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_es.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/> 
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Spanish"/> 
  </analyzer> 
  <analyzer type="query"> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/> 
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/> 
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_es.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/> 
    <filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory" dictionary="es_ES.dic" affix="es_ES.aff" ignoreCase="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Spanish"/> 
  </analyzer> 
</fieldtype>
```

Comment: What more have you tried? After adding a field type (you might want to look at the `text_es` type in the default schema as well), you'll have to reference the fieldType in the field definition (`<field type="textTypeWithStemming" name="text" indexed="true" stored="true">`)

Comment: I don't have a default schema... I have only one schema
I have now replaced <fieldtype name="textTypeWithStemming" class="solr.TextField"> by <fieldType name="text_es" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100"> because i noticed that i didn't have a text_es

Comment: No, the name isn't important. I'm not talking about your default schema, but the Solr 4.9.0 distribution includes a collection of examples, where the default example has a text_es type defined with Spanish handling of stemming etc. (see example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml)

Comment: Yes. That's the part i modified, because the default schema didn't include the es_ES.dic and es_ES.aff.

Comment: But, what else i have to modify?

Comment: You'll need a field that references the fieldType, then index documents with content for that field (as mentioned in the first comment).

Comment: How can I do that? I am sorry but I am new with solr.
Could you give me more info?

Comment: See my first comment. You should really try to get Solr working first and understand the basics, then move on to details like spanish stemming etc.

Comment: Solr is made up of cores, each core represents an index, each index contains documents, each document contains fields. The composition of each field is described in the document definition of the schema.xml. Each document definition may make use of a fieldType. And you have just thrown in a new fieldType, just not enough. Read some tutorials about solr configuration :)